# uploading and getting image link from Amazon S3

Tags: html, image, amazon-s3

On Amazon S3, i've made a bucket, and uploaded some images there.

I wanted to use the 'links' on html `src` for the image.

but when I used the link given, the link shows this page:
[image]

so, what could have gone wrong?

I think this could be very ambiguous question.. and could be way over my ability... I hope someone could help me.

Or could there be other ways to upload image somewhere and use it for your online page?

Comment: you need the set the permission and make it as public

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the image public. When you select the image in S3 this should appear in the "Actions" drop down as an option. Or when you click on the image in S3, it will show this as a button.

Comment: what should I do if it shows an error : Access denied

Comment: You need to ask someone with the right access to do it.